# Problem with reading certain amounth of bits from stream

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, bit, bit-shift

I have code which reads blocks of bits with size from 1 to 8. Homewer, it doesn't work right.

```
        private byte BitRead = 8;
        private ushort ValRead = 0;

        private byte[]  And = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01, 0x03, 0x07, 0x0F, 0x1F, 0x3F, 0x7F, 0xFF };
        private byte[] IAnd = new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xFE, 0xFC, 0xF8, 0xF0, 0xE0, 0xC0, 0x80, 0x00 };

        public byte ReadBit(byte Bits)
        {
            Bit = 0;
            if (BitRead > 7)
            { 
                BitRead -= 8; 
                Bit = 0; 
                ValRead = (ushort)((ValRead << 8) | (byte)stream.ReadByte()); 
            }
            Bit = (byte)((ValRead >> (8 - BitRead - Bits)) & And[Bits]);
            BitRead += Bits;
            return Bit;
        }
```

For example this section with 16 3-bit values: `00 04 01 09 C4 D8`

Would be like that in normal case:
And from my code:

`0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 4, 2, 0, 3, 0`

Same goes for 16 5-bit values: `84 1F 07 BD EE 73 9E F7 39 CE`

Normal case:
My code:

`16, 16, 15, 16, 15, 15, 15, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 14, 14, 14, 14
16,  0, 15,  0,  0, 15,  0, 14, 14,  0, 15,  0,  0, 14,  0, 14`

Comment: The problem is probably in some of your calculations. It is hard to see the actual bug from the code alone. Have you tried using the debugger?

Comment: I think the counting in `BitRead` goes wrong. In your second example, it is 5 after the first call and then the shift operation shifts by (8 - 5 - 5) = -2 bits, which will not do what you want.

Comment: `Bit` is undeclared @ `Bit = 0`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I done this. Thank you [PMF](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2905768/pmf) for pointing me to the problem.

```
        private byte Bit = 0;
        private byte BitRead = 0;
        private long ValRead = 0;

        private readonly byte[] And = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01, 0x03, 0x07, 0x0F, 0x1F, 0x3F, 0x7F, 0xFF };

        public byte ReadBit(byte Bits)
        {
            if (8 - BitRead - Bits < 0)
            {
                BitRead = (byte)-(8 - BitRead - Bits);
                ValRead = (ushort)((ValRead << 8) | (byte)stream.ReadByte());
                Bit = (byte)((ValRead >> 8 - BitRead) & And[Bits]);
            }
            else
            {
                Bit = (byte)((ValRead >> (8 - BitRead - Bits)) & And[Bits]);
                BitRead += Bits;
            }
            return Bit;
        }
```